# Asked for login twice

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

When I do an in-app purchase using the Sandbox, I will get the completion dialog and then it will pop-up an new login box. When I fill this second box with the same details as before it says...

> iTunes account creation not allowed. This Apple ID cannot be used with
>   the iTunes store at this time. Please try again later.

It does this every time I do an in-app purchase.

What does it mean?

Could it be related to this...

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40407930/how-to-remove-in-app-consumables-that-are-stuck-in-receipt

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you really have created the special Sandbox account for testing your in-app purchase:

- First, make sure you are testing *on a device*. You absolutely cannot test in-app purchase on the Simulator.
- Second, make sure you really are using the Sandbox account. You will need to have signed out of iCloud on the device first. (I wish I had a nickel for every time I've forgotten to do this.)

Comment: Its done it for weeks. I presume its a sandbox account because its listed on iTunes Connect as a sand box user. I can't log in from settings, only the app.

Comment: Perhaps its related to this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40407930/how-to-remove-in-app-consumables-that-are-stuck-in-receipt

Comment: Yes, its the message about not being able to create an account that I receive when trying to log in from settings. When I log in via the app though, settings shows the sandbox account as the logged in account.

Comment: Sorry, you want to log _out_ in Settings, not _in_. My apologies.

Comment: Is it possible to log in via setting using a sandbox account?

Comment: The duplicate looks promising. I wonder why it lets me do purchases at all if the account is made invalid.